# Error "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" in jenkins job console

Tags: java, docker, jenkins

I have setup of jenkins (EC2) and have a dedicated docker host (EC2) on which we run jobs, we have docker cloud configured under jenkins configuration. When a user runs his job it is runs on docker host and after some time it fails with this error.

FATAL: Java heap space

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Finished: FAILURE

Since the job runs on docker host, do i have to increase the heap on docker host or on jenkins?

Comment: Please add some more information regarding the job output before it fails with that error. most probably you'll have to increase the heap on the host the job is executed, so yes the docker host.

Comment: Please share info like, which version of JVM, type of EC2, Operating system. Present memory allocated, etc. Also, please profile your JVM using JProfiler or some other toll to see really what is causing the issue. Few other points, There are a few ways you can ensure that Jenkins is going to keep up with your CI/CD needs. One straightforward way is to vertically scale the EC2 instance by changing the instance size. Another way would be to configure the Jenkins Amazon EC2 Container Service Plugin so as to farm out build jobs to Jenkins slave tasks on an ECS cluster.

Comment: I think I found one option where I can pass the JVM options, one is under Docker Templates - Advanced - JVM Options and the other would e to create an image with the heap size set to a particular value.

Comment: @Patrick yes, you are right it should be set for the container on the docker host. I believe we wouldnt want to set a higher heap value on the docker host as every container would have that as the default heap size.